# How to use sagemaker pipeline parameters in a processing step?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to pass a parameter to my sagemaker pipeline and use it in my processing step. I am defining my step as follows:

```
from sagemaker.processing import Processor
    
my_processor = Processor(role=role,
                         image_uri='xxxx',
                         instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
                         instance_count=1,
                         entrypoint=[ "python", "processing.py"])

step_process = ProcessingStep(
        name="ProcessStep",
        processor=my_processor)
```

My pipeline is defined as:

```
from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline import Pipeline
from sagemaker.workflow.parameters import (ParameterString)

filename = ParameterString(
    name='filename',
    default_value='xyz.json'
)


pipeline_name = "ProcessPipeline"

pipe = Pipeline(
    name=pipeline_name,
    parameters=[filename],
    steps=[step_process]
)
```

I am trying to access the parameters as follows in processing.py:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--filename', type=str, dest='filename')
args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
my_obj=s3.get_object(Bucket = 'my_bucket', Key = args.filename)
```

The pipeline execution on sagemaker UI shows that the parameter has been correctly passed. However, arg.filename returns None in processing.py. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Pipeline Parameters can be used at the Pipeline configuration level. If you want to use the parameters in your script, you could look at setting an Environment variable of the Job and ingesting that Environment variable in your script.

```
filename = ParameterString(
            name="filename",
            default_value="xyz.json")
```

```
my_processor = Processor(role=role,
                         image_uri='xxxx',
                         instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
                         instance_count=1,
                         entrypoint=[ "python", "processing.py"],
                         env={"filename":filename}
)
```

Then in your `processing.py`:

```
import os

filename = os.environ.get('filename')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
my_obj=s3.get_object(Bucket = 'my_bucket', Key = filename)
```